# How to instantiate a Singleton only once in my app and its libraries?

Tags: android, singleton, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a library with Firebase Cloud Messaging for me, so I can use that in my apps and all other libraries I created. It is working so far.

Then I added a FcmManager class, which manages all Fcm related stuff, like refresh token. Since I can use this FcmLibrary in my app and its other libraries, I would like to make it a Singleton, so that this FcmManager is instantiated only once. The problem here is in FcmManager I have a `Context` parameter. In activities:

```
val fcmManager = FcmManager(this)
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Does it need an `Activity` instance or simply `applicationContext` will do?